# Spring MVC Websockets with STOMP - Authenticate against specific channels

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

Is there a way in `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` (Spring Boot)  to intercept the registration of users to a specific channel?

I have a basic authentication done in `registerStompEndpoints` using a HandshakeHandler:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
   HandshakeHandler handler = new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {
      @Override
      protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, 
            WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
       Principal principal = request.getPrincipal();
       if (principal == null) {
         return () -> getPrincipal();
       }
       return principal;
     }
   };
   registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
    .setHandshakeHandler(handler)
    .setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}
```

Now I would like to prevent this user from registering to '/topic/admin/news' if the user does not have the permission 'admin'. I'm not using Spring Security. I'd like to have an interceptor before the registration to a channel happens.

As an alternative, I'd like to use the `SimpMessagingTemplate` to only send out messages to users from the channel that have the permission. Is there a way to see what users are currently connected to my stomp-connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.setInterceptors(new TopicSubscriptionInterceptor());
}
```

And the interceptor:

```
public class TopicSubscriptionInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

private static Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicSubscriptionInterceptor.class);

@Override
public Message<?> postReceive(Message<?> message, MessageChannel chanenel) {
    return message;
}

@Override
public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel chanel, boolean sent) {
}

@Override
public boolean preReceive(MessageChannel channel) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor= StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand()) && headerAccessor.getHeader("simpUser") !=null &&  headerAccessor.getHeader("simpUser") instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) headerAccessor.getHeader("simpUser");
        if(!validateSubscription((User)userToken.getPrincipal(), headerAccessor.getDestination()))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No permission for this topic");
        }
    }
    return message;
}

private boolean validateSubscription(User principal, String topicDestination)
{
    logger.debug("Validate subscription for {} to topic {}",principal.getUsername(),topicDestination);
    //Validation logic coming here
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.